# making a directory in a shared drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have an environment with shared drives (ex. \\hello\df\appl\impl)
I need to create a new directory in the shared drive from a remote computer by running a scheduled job that will run PowerShell or CMD commands. I can do it fine with the PowerShell command in the remote computer as shown below, but the network drive has been a problem because I can only use the path as above without the shared path host name.

```bsh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path E:\comp\hello\newdir
```

Please let me know how I could go about creating the new directory in the shared drive (ex. \\hello\df\appl\impl\new directory).

Comment: Why can't you use the hostname in the path? eg... \\server\path\to\newdir

Comment: I am not able to specify the Server were the shared directory is because it could be any. Servers can be changed without notice and what is always constant is the shared directory. need to just use the shared path without specifying the server host. thank you for your reply and the question.

Comment: In addition, I also can't specify the drive letter for the same reason. thanks.

Comment: How will you know what server name to use?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you specify the full path for the shared drive?

So instead of:

```
new-item -itemtype directory -path "\\SharedDrive\Test\New Directory"
```

It would be:

```
new-item -itemtype directory -path "\\Server\Drive$\Test\New Directory"
```

Comment: the host where I use \\SharedDrive\Test\NewDir has the user authority to all shared drives in the network. the host name and drive letter is not necessary to reach it so my predicament is being able to create a directory without using \\Server\Drive$\ because it could be any server and/or drive.